# loop splited string in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

have a string($string) and a Column(DOMAIN) in a table like this:

```
$string="'domain3','domain2,'domain1'";
-----------------
|     DOMAIN    |
|---------------|
|     domain1   |
|     domain2   |
|domain1,domain2|
-----------------
```

And I am trying to create a sql query that return a result if the domain is included in the string. What I found is that I have to split the entries in the column, so I have something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(DOMAIN, ',', 1) IN ('$string')
```

But this gives me a result only if the first index match, I want to do a kind of loop.
I don't know if my question is clear enough, but to explain the context, I am trying to filter results using checkboxes.
Thanks!

Comment: This table layout will most likely result in low database performance because your search triggers a full table scan + string comparision/search. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

What you get as results is right. You only substring from the 1st index. What you are looking for an explode functionality in mysql.

You can read the comments on this page for a plethora of solutions to the string-splitting problem: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html.